# Generate graph automatically based on a set of data table in excel using VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, graph

I'm very new in VBA.. Currently I'm on my project which required me to creating a automation tool by plotting 2 bar chart automatically based on 2 table data as shown below

[image]

However as the table data was generated out from another automation tool thus the number of rows can be increase or decrease. And the number of rows could be more/less than 5, I couldn't select the cells by specifying the address of the cell such as "A7" or "B6".

And these are the expected output of the chart:

[image]

Hope some kind soul could help me on this..

Comment: Please show us your code, and we can suggest the best ways to modify it for your specific needs.  Cheers.

Comment: Could you explain what "creating an automation tool" means? Do you have any tool you are using now, or are you starting from nothing? Can you show us the "another automation tool" that is generating the data? Can you have that tool also include the number of rows, or ranges like `A7:C11` the data is in?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a macro.
All you need is some dynamic named ranges:
[Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830287)

And set your data range to those named ranges.

Answer (score 0):

If the different blocks of data in a given worksheet are separated by blank rows and columns, and the bloc you want is the only one containing the word "Date", you could use a simple VBA routine to find the word "Date", determine the block of data is sits within, and insert a chart using that data. Like the following:

```
Sub PlotRangeUsingFind()
  Const SFind As String = "Date"
  Dim rng As Range
  On Error Resume Next
  Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(SFind).CurrentRegion
  If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
      .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
      .SetSourceData rng
    End With
  End If
End Sub
```

You can modify this to look for any unique word in the block of data. It need not be the entire cell's contents; for example, you could use "Accepted" based on your screenshot.